# how to notify user about notification which has shown but did not repsonded

Tags: cordova, localnotification

i am displaying local notification using [this.](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/)
it is working fine displaying alert on time. Now i want to add remainder of that notification. it is possible to remind user that a notification is pending?

i want to remind him three time about notification that it is pending. if did not the it will be reschedule after one week

Comment: Set a boolean based on whether they've reacted to the notification or not. For all notifications that have not been 'reacted to', display them again?

Comment: i want to remind him three time about notification that it is pending. if did not the it will be reschedule after one week

Comment: i dont know why minus?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like what user DeeMac already suggested. What you need to do is to keep track of the state of notifications sent with something like this:

```
var notClicked = [];

window.plugin.notification.local.onclick(function(id, state, json) {
    // Iterate through the notClicked and remove the one with same id.
});

var id = "...";
window.plugin.notification.local.add({id: id});
notClicked.push({id: id, remindersSent: 0});

setTimeout(function() {
    // Here loop through your data structure and 
    // for each item send the reminder and increase the remindersSent by one
    // if remindersSent == 3, handle it as you wish (add reminder for one week from now)
}, 10000); // Every tenth second
```

The example doesn't try to be ready code for you to use, you need to alter it to fulfill your needs.